# Isomorphisms of the ring of truncated polynomials over the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, complex-numbers, formal-power-series

I have to prove that the factor ring $\mathbb{C}[[z]]/z^m\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is isomorphic to the ring of truncated polynomials $\mathbb{C}[z]/(z^m)$, where $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is the ring of formal power series over the complex numbers, but I can't come up with any specific ring isomorphism to prove it with. I know that every ideal in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is of the form $(z^m)$ for some $m$, but i can't see how that will help, unless there is some way of identifying $(z^m)$ and $z^m\mathbb{C}[[z]]$.

Comment: This would be the standard way of solving this problem: There is an obvious inclusion $\Bbb C[z] \to \Bbb C[[z]]$, which you can compose with the canonical map $\Bbb C[[z]]\to \Bbb C[[z]]/z^m\Bbb C[[z]]$. Check that the kernel of the composition is $(z^m)$, and confirm that it is surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, that makes perfect sense. I was wondering whether the fact that $\text{Ker}(\phi \circ i)$, where $i$ is the usual inclusion and $\phi$ is the canonical map, is always an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ already implies the equality $\text{Ker}(\phi \circ i)=(z^{m})$ for som $m$ since I know all ideals are of this form or whether this requires a further argument?

Comment: Furthermore, how is it possible to prove surjectivity directly, since the elements of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]/z^{m}\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ are just the series $h(z)$ with the first non-zero coefficient equal to $h_{m}$? I can't seem to find some polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ which will be mapped to such an element.

Comment: Nevermind I have figured it out. Thank you very much!